# Laravel Blade template Form::open() to Html

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am following a tutorial about Laravel.

However, I want to convert the blade template `Form::open()` to html/php form, to make it easier to read & understand.

This is the Blade template:

```
   {{ Form::open(['action'=> ['StudentController@destroy', $student->id], 'method'=>'POST']) }}
            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
            {{ Form::submit('Delete',['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) }}
   {{ Form::close() }}
```

I need to convert the blade code to html/php
I tried it multiple times, something like this. but **failed**.

```
    <form action="url('StudentController@destroy', $student->id)" method="POST">
        <?php method_field('Delete'); ?>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
    </form>
```

Anyone know the correct html/php form?

[edit] Route:list
[image]

Comment: i  am using version 5.5

Comment: can you please show your route

Comment: routes/web/  it was like this "Route::resource('student', 'StudentController');

Comment: `<form action="{{ url('StudentController@destroy', $student->id) }}" method="POST">`, for starters.

Comment: `{{ url('/students', ['id' => $student->id])}}` and inside form add `<input type='_method' value='DELETE' /> and <input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a controller action you need to use `url()->action(...)` (or `action()`) for short.

```
<form action="{{url()->action('StudentController@destroy', ['id'=>$student->id])}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    {{ method_field('DELETE'); }}
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

This is also described in [the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls#urls-for-controller-actions)

Comment: Thanks there was an error at first saying "expired page" but when I added " @csrf " it Worked, also I changed "{{ method_field() }}" to 
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" /> to make it all html

Answer (score 2):

try this way

use `{{}}` and use `route`

```
 <form action="{{route('StudentController@destroy', ['id'=>$student->id])}}" method="POST">
    <?php method_field('Delete'); ?>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use this code

```
<form action="{{ url('StudentController@destroy', $student->id) }}" method="POST">
    <input type='_method' value='DELETE' />
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i updated the code please try and let me know if there is any issue

Comment: "laravelone.me/StudentController@destroy/2" it sent me here, in the tutorial it was sent to "laravelone.me/Students/7"

Comment: run php artisan route:list and first check your route name and share it with me

Comment: this one? "DELETE    | students/{student}      | students.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@destroy  | web"

Answer (score 1):

In your 'action' on the form, you need to enclose any helper functions within brackets so that Blade knows what to do with this, otherwise, it's just text.

Also note, I removed 'method_field' and replaced it with the hidden field, as this is essentially what `method_field` helper creates.

```
<form action="{{route('StudentController@destroy', ['id' => $student->id])}}" method="POST">
        <input type='hidden' value='DELETE'>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

If using the `route` helper isn't working, you could use a more simple approach for the 'action' param of the form tag:

```
<form action="/student/destroy/{{$student->id}}" method="POST">
```

Comment: it sent me to this url "http://laravelone.me/StudentController@destroy/7",

Comment: @Van, I've updated the code to use the `route` helper, give that a shot and let me know what happens for you.

Comment: it says "Route [StudentController@destroy] not defined.

Comment: As mentioned above then, attach the structure / code of your routes.php file so we can see what we're working with.

Comment: routes>web> "Route::resource('student', 'StudentController'); just this code

Comment: @Van put `php artisan route:list` and attach it to your code above.